# Columns with White Spaces not displaying in Gridview

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

i have data that i have extracted to csv and read the data and display to gridview. data is displaying if column contains one word, however when column contains two words no data is displayed, one of the example column in the code is Short Description. below is my code

```
    Dim fi As New FileInfo("C:\NotBackedUp\TSD_Trove\OutageDashboard DB\exeloutage.csv")
    Dim connectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Extended Properties=Text;Data Source=" & fi.DirectoryName

    Dim conn As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
    conn.Open()

    'the SELECT statement is important here, 
    'and requires some formatting to pull dates and deal with headers with spaces.
    Dim cmdSelect As New OleDbCommand("SELECT Begin, Number, Message, Short description  FROM " & fi.Name, conn)

    Dim adapter1 As New OleDbDataAdapter
    adapter1.SelectCommand = cmdSelect

    Dim ds As New DataSet
    adapter1.Fill(ds, "DATA")

    Outage_DashBoard.Gridview_OutageDashboard.DataSource = ds.Tables(0).DefaultView
    conn.Close()
```

Comment: This question has zero to do with VBScript so I removed that tag. If you had read the tag description then you would have known that it was inappropriate, so make sure to read tag descriptions before applying tags.

Comment: There's no point creating a `DataSet` if you are only going to use one `DataTable`. Just create a `DataTable`. Also, there's no point binding the `DefaultView` of a `DataTable`.  Just bind the `DataTable`.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL parser can't determine that "Short description" is a single identifier.  You should avoid using spaces and other special characters in column names and other identifiers, e.g. use `ShortDescription`, but, if you insist on doing so, you must escape them in your SQL code.  When using the Jet OLE DB provider and in various other cases, that means using brackets, i.e. `[Short description]`.